# Product and Category relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, associations, self-referencing-table

Trying to have following relationship in my application.

Product can belong to many categories, sub categories and sub sub categories.

Current design:

```
Product:
    has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
    has_many :sub_categories, through: :categorizations
    has_many :sub_sub_categories, through: :categorizations

Category:
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :products, through: :categorizations
    has_many :sub_categories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
    belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

Categorization:
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :sub_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'sub_category_id'
    belongs_to :sub_sub_category, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'sub_sub_category_id'
    belongs_to :product
```

products of a particular category can be listed as `category.products`.

How to access products of a particular `sub_category` and `sub_sub_category`?

What changes should I make??

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `has_many :sub_sub_categories, through: :sub_categories` to the `Product` model.

```
## app/models/product.rb
has_many :sub_categories
has_many :categories, through: :sub_categories
has_many :sub_sub_categories, through: :sub_categories
```

If I were you, I would design like this:

```
Product:
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

Categorization:
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :category

Category:
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', optional: true
    has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :nullify

    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :products, through: :categorizations
```

Note: Add `parent_id` to table `categories`

Comment: Thank you.. And above design is fine or using self-referential relationship in `category` instead of `sub_category` is better?